# Best way to use food database API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I'm currently working on a node/react application that will make use of a food database API like the one offered by the USDA.

My question is, how are these APIs best used in order to limit API calls?

For example, autocomplete, as a user is typing into the search field for a food, i want to give them a list of say 10-20 possible options based on what they typed. However, as they continue to refine what they type in, this is going to generate multiple API calls in order to return possible items. What is the best way to limit the amount of calls?

Is it better to somehow store the data locally? It's a massive database that the USDA has, I'm not sure it's feasible or even allowed to be copied necessarily.

Any other time I have dealt with APIs it has just been a call here or there but nothing like this and I guess I'm just confused on where to get started with it.

Comment: debounce / throttle requests

Comment: only autocomplete after 3 characters

Comment: @shadoe2020 I considered this option, but after 3 characters I would need to limit the calls. I guess my true question here is, is it better to only use API calls to the database or to someone store some or all of it locally to prevent having to use the API all the time.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli good point, I will need to look into this. Thank you

Comment: I think it's going to be unique to your situation. I'd develop non-locally and then make a decision from there because it wont really take much to move it locally code-wise.